# Installing dabl Package

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install dabl package and it throws the following error:

> pip install dabl
>
> Collecting dabl
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dabl (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for dabl

Comment: There is no package called "dabl" on the [PyPi index](https://pypi.org/search/?q=dabl).  Where are you trying to install it from?

Comment: That package is still under development on [GitHub](https://github.com/amueller/dabl).  You will need to clone the repo and install from the local source.

Comment: Or install via `pip install git+https://github.com/amueller/dabl/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined comments from [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5003756/james) and [hoefling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2650249/hoefling).

There is no package called "dabl" on the [PyPi index](https://pypi.org/search/?q=dabl). That package is still under development on [GitHub](https://github.com/amueller/dabl). You will need to clone the repo and install from the local source. Or install via

```
pip install git+https://github.com/amueller/dabl/
```